# Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 Amd/Intel Graphics, Fan and Battery Life problem

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, battery, fan

I am new to linux and ubuntu so i am having problems with it. I have dell inspiron 5521 which has hybrid graphics. My problem is that i can not switch between graphic cards -vgaswitcheroo does not work- and i can not install amd catalyst center and amd graphics driver correctly. I read every page written about it. One time i thought i managed to install and restart xserver than ubuntu did not boot again so i had to reinstall. Now because of the graphics driver problems my fans are always working and battery life is about 1.5 hours which was +4-5 hours in Windows 8.1.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely read the official [BinaryDriverHowto/AMD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) guide.

The whole point is to install amd graphics driver first (you are given instructions for that on BinaryDriverHowto/AMD guide), and then apply some fix to be found in here on AskUbuntu, for amd drivers, assuming  they won't work fine after reboot.

Intel drivers for Ubuntu can be found on [Intel official page](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) for Linux drivers. Check out section Intel(R) Graphics Installer 1.0.6 for Linux.

After installing drivers for both video cards, I understand that you can easily switch your video cards at your own discretion right from the Amd catalyst center.

Comment: I am sorry it could be my fault but it seems like in the first link i should install fglrx and then in the second link i should remove fglrx to login.

Comment: You're right, my bad, edited answer after your reply. That guy wanted to disable Ati card to save battery power, and use after that only one video card out of two. [Ati drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) can be installed right from the desktop after you download them (choose the correct version for your video card). As for Graphics Installer 1.0.6 for Linux, 2 other people in here who used that link I gave them told me it worked fine and that they are pleased with the results. I am a beginner, I know very few about Linux, sorry. So you try it or you wait for a detailed answer.